# Compute a new max value of an opencv histogram according to a percentage limit of pixels

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, histogram

I have a 32FC1 opencv mat. 
I would like to compute its histogram and according to a percentage limit ( for example 99.7 % ), find the corresponding value (new max) on the range of possible value with my 32FC1.

For example, the range of used values in a Mat is between 0 and 1000.
But I only want to keep the range of my histogram where there are 99.7% of the pixels.
So I would like to find the new max limit value where 99.7% of my total Mat pixels are before.

How can I do that ?